# Bind Integer to Fill Rectangle with color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Rectangle in my WPF application which I want to fill with a color. This color is based on the value in my code. This value can go from 0 to 1023.

If the value is 0, I want the Rectangle to be filled black until full White for the value 1023.

I know I need some kind of converter to do this, but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong, I don't have that much experience with the IValueConverters.

In my XAML code I Have the following code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <root:IntegerToColorConverter x:Key="integerColorConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

And The converter converter is used like this in the XAML Code:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="{Binding Path=LightDiodeValue, Converter={StaticResource integerColorConverter}}" Width="10" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,60"/>
</Grid>
```

When The Page is shown, the IntegerToColorConverter is called and I can see it creates the SolidBrush with the values that I expect and then returns it, but for some reason the Rectangle isn't filled with this SolidBrush .

The Converter looks like this:

```
class IntegerToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int iValue = (int)value;
            iValue = iValue * 255 / 1024; //Convert from  1024 range to 255 range
            Color customColor = Color.FromArgb(255, iValue, iValue, iValue);
            SolidBrush integerBrush = new SolidBrush(customColor);

            return integerBrush ;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            SolidBrush brush = (SolidBrush)value;

            int iValue = (brush.Color.R + brush.Color.G + brush.Color.B) * 1024 / 255 / 3;
            return iValue;
        }
    }
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: SolidBrush is the wrong type. It's WinForms. Use `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush`. You should generally not use any types from System.Drawing in a WPF application. Remove the reference to the System.Drawing assembly.

Comment: Ok that was a pretty dumb mistake, indeed that resolved it...